# Large n small p regression - Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, pca, cart

In the area of machine learning, most of the algorithms are intended for small n large p problems. I am familiar with the statistical techniques of PCA, etc but was wondering what algorithms are available in the machine learning area for similar analysis work. The aim is to determine the effect of a limited number of predictor variables on the outcome using robust methods such as pca in the ML domain,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: p referring to ?

Comment: It may be helpful to search this site for: lasso, elastic net, support vector machines; and perhaps supervised PCA and partial least squares in relation to dimension reduction followed by prediction. All of these handle the case where p (number variables) is larger than n (number samples).

Comment: @julieth - the OP is asking for large n small p (n>>p), not the othe way around.

Comment: In that case, the first set of search terms should get the OP started (drop supervised PCA and PLS). With n>>p, penalized methods not mandatory, but can still perform well if the goal is prediction.

Comment: you may want to look into things like additive models and GAMs

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate, but this was based on a mis-reading the title as asking about $n<p$ and not about $n>p$. Now I see that it is not a duplicate, but instead an unclear question. If I could, I would vote to close as unclear.

Comment: A large sample size & few potential predictors is the relatively unproblematic case. So wouldn't the answer just  be a list of supervised learning methods?